# Problem fixing Future warning: .ix is deprecated. Please use .loc for label based indexing or .iloc for positional indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I have a piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import linregress
from dao.pair.adfvalues import adfval

__all__=['df_test']

_col_diff='diff'
_col_orig='orig'
_col_shift='shift'

class DfTest(object):
    def __init__(self,confidence_interval,sample_size):
        self.critical_val=adfval(1,'c',sample_size,confidence_interval)
        self.test_stat=float('nan')

    def is_pass(self,sample):
        self.data=pd.DataFrame({_col_orig:sample}).sort_index(ascending=False)
        self.data[_col_shift]=self.data.loc[:,_col_orig].shift()
        self.data[_col_diff]=self.data.loc[:,_col_orig].diff()

        slope,intercept,_,_,stderr=linregress(
                self.data.ix[1:,_col_shift],self.data.ix[1:,_col_diff])
        self.test_stat=slope/stderr
        return self.test_stat<self.critical_val

    def __repr__(self):
        return "DfTest: {} vs critical val {}".format(
                self.test_stat,self.critical_val)
```

That is giving me the following Future Warning:

```
FutureWarning:
.ix is deprecated. Please use
.loc for label based indexing or
.iloc for positional indexing

See the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated
  return getattr(section, self.name)[new_key]
```

I have tried changing the line which uses ix from:

```
slope,intercept,_,_,stderr=linregress(
                    self.data.ix[1:,_col_shift],self.data.ix[1:,_col_diff])
```

to:

```
slope,intercept,_,_,stderr=linregress(
                    self.data.loc[1:,_col_shift],self.data.loc[1:,_col_diff])
```

but this just gives me a new error:

```
    start_slice, end_slice = self.slice_locs(start, end, step=step, kind=kind)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5248, in slice_locs
    start_slice = self.get_slice_bound(start, "left", kind)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5160, in get_slice_bound
    label = self._maybe_cast_slice_bound(label, side, kind)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py", line 1101, in _maybe_cast_slice_bound
    self._invalid_indexer("slice", label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3340, in _invalid_indexer
    form=form, klass=type(self), key=key, kind=type(key)
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [1] of <class 'int'>
```

I have also tried changing `ix` to `iloc` without success as well.

What do I need to do to eliminate this future warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.ix` is difficult because it provided *both* label and integer based selection. For good reason it was deprecated (and with `1.0.0` removed) as such indexing becomes ambiguous.

Your row indexer is position based, your column indexer is label based. You can use `Index.get_loc` to turn a label into position indexer. So replace `self.data.ix[1:,_col_shift]` with

```
self.data.iloc[1:, self.data.columns.get_loc(_col_shift)]
```

---

Since you are only selecting data it's fine to use chained selection. Chained **assignment** is the thing to avoid.

```
self.data.iloc[1:][col_shift]  # self.data.iloc[1:].loc[:, col_shift]
```